# Scrub a string using regex in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am cleansing a large data file in Pandas.  One column ('ID') contains a mix of strings and integers.  Where there is more than one record for a particular ID, the user convention has been to append '*'(asterisk) and a sequence number.

I need to add a column to the DF ('CleanID') and duplicates the ID or, for any ID that contains asterisk strips the '*' plus all subsequent characters.  So:

```
ID           CleanID
A1000*1      A1000
A1000*2      A1000
B200         B200
457          457
```

Etc

Answer (score 3):

Use `pd.Series.str.replace`

```
df['CleanID'] = df.ID.astype(str).str.replace('\*.*', '')
df

        ID CleanID
0  A1000*1   A1000
1  A1000*2   A1000
2     B200    B200
3      457     457
```

---

Use `pd.Series.str.split`

```
df['CleanID'] = df.ID.astype(str).str.split('*').str[0]
df

        ID CleanID
0  A1000*1   A1000
1  A1000*2   A1000
2     B200    B200
3      457     457
```